# Fullcalendar, returning custom data via json

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar

I need help bringing some data from a json file via Fullcalendar, but I can't.

My JS code, where I instantiated the calendar and called the json file.

But I can't bring in data other than: start, end, title.

I need the data:
professional
patient
health insurance

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
         var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

locale: 'pt-br',
initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
navLinks: true,

headerToolbar: {
left: 'prev,next',
center: 'title',
right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
},

events: { url: "../server/consulta/list_consultas.php" },

//CLICK ON EVENT
eventClick: function(info) {
$('#modalConsulta #inicio').text(info.event.start).toLocaleString();
$('#modalConsulta #profissional').text(info.event.profissional);
$('#modalConsulta #paciente').text(info.event.paciente);
$('#modalConsulta #convenio').text(info.event.convenio);
$('#modalConsulta').modal('show');
return false;
}

});

calendar.render();
});
```

I was looking to bring the data saved in the database inside a modal with js via json

Comment: Read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing to understand what fullCalendar does with extra fields that you put into an event object's JSON:  _"Every other non-standard property will be transferred over to the extendedProps hash in the Event Object."_